# Execute retire.js commands from java application

Tags: java, npm

I'm using `retire.js` to identify security vulnerabilities of js files. I want to integrate `retire.js` with my java app which means I want to execute `retire.js` commands from my java application. For maven, We can use the [maven shared invoker](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html). Similar to this, are there any libraries or alternative ways to execute `retire.js` commands.

Eg: get security vulnerabilities or list of CVE of JQuery using API call

Answer (score 0):

You should check the maven retire.js plugin:
https://github.com/h3xstream/burp-retire-js/tree/master/retirejs-maven-plugin